# Como obter valor de um json?

Tags: c#

Eu uso `WebClient` e `DownloadString` para recuperar json:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var teste = wc.DownloadString($"https://api.vagalume.com.br/search.php?musid=l3ade68b8g72d4ffa3&apikey=69d03116fe65f19839140520a79f59f6");
}
```

Segue variável `teste` gerado em string:

```
{
    "type": "exact",
    "art": {
        "id": "3ade68b7gb6412ea3",
        "name": "De Las Alturas de Los Andes",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/de-las-alturas-de-los-andes\/"
    },
    "mus": [{
        "id": "3ade68b8g72d4ffa3",
        "name": "Assim Como a Corsa",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/de-las-alturas-de-los-andes\/assim-como-a-corsa.html",
        "lang": 1,
        "text": "Assim como a corsa anseia por \u00e0guas\nComo a terra seca 
        precisa da chuva\nMeu cora\u00e7\u00e3o tem sede de ti\nRei meu, e Deus 
        meu!\n\nFaz chover... senhor Jesus!\nDerrama chuva neste lugar!\nVem com 
        teu rio... senhor jesus!\nInundar meu cora\u00e7\u00e3o!\n\nAssim como a 
        corsa anseia por \u00e0guas\nComo a terra seca precisa da chuva\nMeu 
        cora\u00e7\u00e3o tem sede de ti\nRei meu, e deus meu!\n\nFaz 
        chover...senhor jesus!\nDerrama chuva neste lugar!\nVem com teu 
        rio...senhor jesus!\nInundar meu cora\u00e7\u00e3o!\n\nVem! vem vem...e 
        faz chover!\nAbra as comportas senhor...e faz chover!\nEsta 
        gera\u00e7\u00e3o precisa da tua chuva...\nEsta gera\u00e7\u00e3o 
        precisa de santidade...\nAviva-nos senhor...vem com a chuva!\nAviva-nos 
        senhor...vem com a chuva!\nAvisa-nos senhor...vem com a chuva...faz 
        chover!\nFaz chover!"
    }],
    "badwords": false
}
```

Como posso obter o valor do parâmetro "text" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instale o pacote [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), depois crie essa três classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Art art { get; set; }
    public Mu[] mus { get; set; }
    public bool badwords { get; set; }
}

public class Art
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Mu
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int lang { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

utilizando o pacote instalado escreve o seguinte código:

```
Rootobject result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
var text = result.mus[0].text; // aqui está o valor do que precisa
```

além do valor que precisa esse código trouxe todos os valores de uma maneira fácil de utilizar.

Comment: Funcionou direitinho  =]

Comment: Virgilio Novic, como faço para retornar um lista ? Porfavor, veja meu post.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda abre outra pergunta

Comment: Virgilio https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258087/como-retornar-uma-lista-de-um-json

Comment: Levei um voto negativo sem motivo