# Como retornar uma lista de um json?

Tags: c#, json

Segue resultado:

> `{"response":{"numFound":2654,"start":0,"docs":[{"id":"l3ade68b8g5db3b0b3","langID":1,"url":"/ministerio-codigo-de-honra/quao-grande.html","title":"QuÃ£o grande","band":"MinistÃ©rio CÃ³digo de Honra"},{"id":"l3ade68b8geb421fa3","langID":1,"url":"/mattos-nascimento/quao-grande.html","title":"QuÃ£o Grande","band":"Mattos Nascimento"},{"id":"l3ade68b8g7acefea3","langID":1,"url":"/andre-valadao/quao-grande-es-tu.html","title":"QuÃ£o Grande Ã‰s Tu","band":"AndrÃ© ValadÃ£o"},{"id":"l3ade68b7g0109aea3","langID":1,"url":"/hinario-adventista/quao-grande-es-tu.html","title":"QuÃ£o Grande Ã©s Tu","band":"HinÃ¡rio Adventista"},{"id":"l3ade68b8g2d4bfea3","langID":1,"url":"/padre-marcelo-rossi/quao-grande-es-tu.html","title":"QuÃ£o Grande Es Tu","band":"Padre Marcelo Rossi"}]},"highlighting":{"l3ade68b8g5db3b0b3":{},"l3ade68b8geb421fa3":{},"l3ade68b8g7acefea3":{},"l3ade68b7g0109aea3":{},"l3ade68b8g2d4bfea3":{}}}`

Como posso gerar uma `list` ou `array` com o resultado acima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a mesma lógica da pergunta [Como obter valor de um json?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247317/como-obter-valor-de-um-json/247320)
o `Json` que retorna em classes, ***exemplo***:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public Highlighting highlighting { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int numFound { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public Doc[] docs { get; set; }
}

public class Doc
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int langID { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string band { get; set; }
}

public class Highlighting
{
    public L3ade68b8g5db3b0b3 l3ade68b8g5db3b0b3 { get; set; }
    public L3ade68b8geb421fa3 l3ade68b8geb421fa3 { get; set; }
    public L3ade68b8g7acefea3 l3ade68b8g7acefea3 { get; set; }
    public L3ade68b7g0109aea3 l3ade68b7g0109aea3 { get; set; }
    public L3ade68b8g2d4bfea3 l3ade68b8g2d4bfea3 { get; set; }
}

public class L3ade68b8g5db3b0b3
{
}

public class L3ade68b8geb421fa3
{
}

public class L3ade68b8g7acefea3
{
}

public class L3ade68b7g0109aea3
{
}

public class L3ade68b8g2d4bfea3
{
}
```

Observação algumas classes estão em aberto, ou seja, sem características de suas propriedades, mas, pelo `Json` é isso que pode ser utilizado.

Sobre os caracteres inválidos utilize `Encoding` assim:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
     wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
}
```

Utilizando o pacote [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), faça:

```
Rootobject result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Comment: `public L3ade68b8g5db3b0b3` é necessário ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda eu fiz de acordo com o `json`, mas, ai é com você se não for só ocultar a classe `Highlighting`

Comment: @MatheusMiranda dá uma explicada melhor na sua pergunta, está levando negativos, faça igual a outra.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda só não esqueça de aceitar como resposta.